# PHP For Loop Directory Listing Doesn't Make Links

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, hyperlink

I have been trying to make a simple php application which reads a directory of images and folders possibly containing other folders and images. Basically it is supposed to read the directory, and then pass on the list to a javascript array which would then show the links to images/directories in a much nicer way (preview and other nice things). This is supposed to be a simple, pretty interface but at this point, I can't even get the php directory reading to work properly.

I currently have the following code:

```
<?php
$dir    = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/';
$files = scandir($dir);

for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
   echo "<href src='/" . $files[$x] . "'>" . $files[$x] . "</href><br>";
}
?>
```

When this code runs, it prints out something like this:

```
.
..
Directory/File name 1
Directory/File name 2
Directory/File name 3
And so on
```

What it is supposed to do is print out all the files and make them into a link to the proper page. What it is doing is exactly that with one exception. When it prints out, I cant click any of the links nor are they blue like they should be. If I inspect element and look at the source, it shows the links properly inserted into the page yet they don't show as links.

This is my main problem right now along with the one dot and the two dots. I am a PHP newbie and have no idea how to get rid of these. I also cant make it not limited to 10 items in the for loop. I have no idea on how to fix any of these issues and I would really appreciate any help on this or maybe just a push in the right direction.

Thanks in advance,
Emanuel

Comment: The syntax is `<a href="xxx"></a>` plus it doesn't use `src`, `<script>` and `img` do. So, pretty sure you meant to use `<a href=....><img src=...></a>`. Time to learn HTML 101.

Comment: `echo href`? is that a new tag? thats not an anchor

Comment: yep, swap href for a and src= for href=

Comment: second thought actually... Perhaps go back to the basic tutorials on HTML

Comment: Yea that's me being the idiot I am :/ Sometimes I just derp majorly like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `a href='link'` for the HTML you are echoing.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
   echo "<a href='/" . $files[$x] . "'>" . $files[$x] . "</a><br>";
}
```

As for the `.` and `..`, those are the current directory and parent directory symbols, respectively. To remove those, you could remove them from the array using this :

```
$files = array_slice(scandir('/path/to/directory/'), 2);
```

---

References (that you should read up on) :

- HTML [a tag](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/a/) (anchor tag)
- [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) manual